# Do I have to have the IP address of a server to initiate a DMCA takedown if the server is behind a service like Cloudflare?

Tags: cloudflare, abuse, dmca

We have some content that is, well, "contested". The site that is misusing our content is being hosted by Cloudflare. I'm concerned that I will need to know the IP address of the server hosting the content in order to issue a DMCA takedown. Does the DMCA have an allowance of some sort for proxied content? Do I have to know the IP address of the real server hosting the content?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should [send your DMCA complaint to CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/abuse/form). Once they process it, [they will tell you where the site is hosted](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200167716-How-do-I-file-a-DMCA-complaint-), at which point you can serve the DMCA on the actual hosting provider.

Comment: What's to stop Cloudflare from taking months to comply? That's the real concern here...

Comment: Why would they take months to comply?!

Comment: @WayneC Indeed, what's in it for them to take months to comply? For a service provider, complying to DMCA notices expeditiously is the requirement for getting an easy out rather than risking being held responsible themselves. http://copyright.gov/onlinesp/

Comment: Whilst this is the correct answer, I've been disappointed in cloudflare's responses to abuse requests that I've submitted to them, so I hope that Wayne was able to get what he wanted from them.

Comment: Abuse report != DMCA takedown request.